# Hebrew Letters showing up in squares in a Hebrew font in Chrome on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have Chrome 44.0.2403.130 running on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)and the Hebrew letters show up in squares.

My encoding is UTF-8.

I uninstalled Google Chrome (using app-cleaner) and reinstalled.

I changed the advanced font settings to all Arial and set them back to their default.

[image]

Comment: Are they in a different font (e.g. David, http://fontzone.net/font-details/david ) that needs to be installed?

Comment: 10.10.5 is a beta, have you reported it to Apple?

Comment: I'm seeing it in Roboto (on the download Google Chrome page) and Open Sans....

Comment: It's working in Safari - it's not working in Chrome - so I don't think it's necessarily an Apple issue...

Comment: I think if you uninstall Open Sans Hebrew it may help?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the address bar and type `chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write` and enable the flag (effectively disabling DirectWrite).

Restart the browser after the change for the flag to take effect.