# Google font rendered incorrectly in Windows Chrome and Opera

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts, opera

Using Chrome 45 on Win10.  The google font 'Roboto Condensed'-Normal 400 is rendering as 'Roboto'. Also happens on Opera 31.  All other browsers (IE, Edge, Firefox, old Win Safari) render correctly. All other styles of 'Roboto Condensed' render correctly.

I assume it is a font cache problem, but where is it and how do I clear it?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and a URL where you encounter this problem?

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with DirectWire on Win 10, so you will need to disable it in Chrome / Opera. see: [http://superuser.com/questions/954309](http://superuser.com/questions/954309)